# Can I fly with a skateboard in my hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, legal, hand-luggage, sport-equipment

Can I fly with a skateboard in my hand luggage? The skateboard can be either assembled or not. I'd rather not pack it in hold luggage to avoid it being damaged or stolen. What I am worried about are the deck and the trucks (i.e. the metal block holding the wheels (see image below)) being construed as a blunt item and thus being not allowed in hand luggage.

[image: Skateboarding trucks]

For completeness sake, I'd like to know the air-travel regulations for both USA and EU regarding this.

Comment: What is the maximum size of your hand luggage on said flight and does your skateboard fit within that size? There are so many options for carry on luggage that I can not make a guess on what you might find.

Comment: I've heard lots of stories of people traveling around Europe who were not allowed to carry on a skateboard, most likely because its counted as a "blunt instrument" whereas they seem to be explicitly allowed in the US

Comment: a quick google search gave me this http://traveltips.usatoday.com/can-skateboard-onto-airplane-travel-another-continent-106525.html

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 Excellent. Wanna make an answer out of it?

Comment: @JoErNanO I wasn't going to make this an answer because it's not based on any real experience, but rather word of mouth, it may be helpful anyhow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is largely dependent on where you are.  In general, the US take a more relaxed approach to skateboards and do allow these to be brought onto flights as carry-on.  However many airports in the EU see the skateboard as a "blunt instrument" and don't allow them regardless of the stance of the airline.

See this article: [Can You Take a Skateboard Onto an Airplane to Travel to Another Continent?](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/can-skateboard-onto-airplane-travel-another-continent-106525.html)

I would recommend searching specifically for experiences at any airlines/airports you may be traveling through and take a cautious approach when traveling through the EU.

Comment: don't they have a rather new rule in US about sport equipment that would encompass skateboards? I read somewhere that you were allowed baseball bats and hockey sticks, now.

Answer (score 3):

No, this seems to have changed. Apparently your trucks could be weaponised.

Checked luggage is rarely stolen, the bigger risk seems to be it going to the wrong airport. If you're worried about theft wrap your bag properly so it's more hassle than it is worth.

People who steal normally are more interested in macbooks and other such luxuries

Comment: Do you have some authoritative references for this?